# How to implement RETWEET in ios 5?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm working on a project to integrate twitter with my iPhone app, and for now post tweet functionality has been achieved (big thanks to twitter frame work in ios 5), and I want to proceed to RE TWEET function, any help would be appreciated.

P.S-Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

Issue a POST request to https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/12354.json from TWRequest (see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/:id for documentation on retweeting via the API). (replace the 12345 with the ID of the tweet the user is retweeting)

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/making-api-requests-twrequest for more information on issuing REST API requests via TWRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Add current date and time with re twitting message, another wise twitter does not receive same message again.

Comment: my question was to implement retweet in iPhone app, have you got any sample code with you, as i didn't get what you have posted now