# Is it possible to do a retweet from within an app via API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, social-framework

I'm making an iPhone app where I get all feeds of a certain user. Now I was wondering if it's possible to do a retweet when you push a button? I'm using the social framework. After some searching through the social framework API, I didn't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's limited Twitter API doesn't seem to cover retweets.
To retweet in iOS you would need to use Twitter's [API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid) 
It looks like you would need to send the POST request yourself and it would look something like 
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/3962807808.json   // Taken from API page.

I've also found this SO post, but there doesn't seem to be an accepted answer
[How to implement RETWEET in ios 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398297/how-to-implement-retweet-in-ios-5)

Here's some sample code for retweeting from [Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/05/twitter-framework-tutorial/)

```
- (void)_retweetMessage:(TwitterMessage *)message
{
    NSString *retweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/%@.json", message.identifier];
    NSURL *retweetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:retweetString];
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:retweetURL parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];
    request.account = _usedAccount;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (responseData)
        {
            NSError *parseError = nil;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&amp;parseError];

            if (!json)
            {
                NSLog(@"Parse Error: %@", parseError);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", json);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Request Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

EDIT: Keab42 pointed out the link is for the Twitter API which will be deprecated early next year.  Here's the updated API page. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid

Comment: In your code snippet there you're using the V1 API which will be switched off in March 2013, suggest you look at how to implement that same code in the 1.1 API or come March you'll have problems.